# How to configure XFCE bottom panel?

Tags: linux, debian, context-menu, xfce4

I switched from Windows to Linux (Sparky Linux based on Debian Testing Jessie) with xfce 4 as
desktop. My problem is that I'm unable to configure my bottom panel:

[image: my bottom panel]

If I right-click it, no context menu appears, the bottom panel just disappears for a moment and reappears. Furthermore this panel is not configurable in the settings for the panels. I can just choose my top panel.

So knowing how to configure the panel by configuration files would help me as well. But of course I would really like to get this working by one of the other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I found out, that the panel isn't a xfce panel. It's a wbar.
With some reading in `man wbar` and `man wbar-configuration` it was easy to configure it
the way it wanted it.

Comment: Why don't you show us how you did it? just the initial procedures.. when I type `man wbar` it says `No manual entry for wbar`. ubuntu 16.04.